# Why const char pointer assigned to another in C?

Tags: arrays, c, pointers

In `compute_scrabble_value` function `const char word[]` is assigned to `const char *p`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define MAX_LEN 30

int compute_scrabble_value(const char *word);

const int scrabble_values[26] = {1, 3, 3, 2,  1, 4, 2, 4, 1, 8, 5, 1, 3,
                                 1, 1, 3, 10, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 4, 8, 4, 10 };

int main(void)
{
    const char word[MAX_LEN + 1];
    printf("Enter a word: ");
    scanf("%s", word);
    printf("Scrabble value: %d", compute_scrabble_value(word));
    
    return 0;
}

int compute_scrabble_value(const char *word)
{
   const char *p = word;
   int total = 0;

   while (*p) {
       total += scrabble_values[toupper(*p++) - 'A'];
   }
      
   return total;
}
```

But even if you don't assign like below, the output seems same.

```
int compute_scrabble_value(const char *word)
{
   int total = 0;

   while (*word) {
       total += scrabble_values[toupper(*word++) - 'A'];
   }

   return total;
}
```

Why is `const char word[]` assigned to another pointer variable?

Comment: Your compiler should complain about `const char word[MAX_LEN + 1]; … scanf("%s", word);` — you can't modify `word` because it is defined with `const`.

Answer (score 0):

There's no programmatic reason to do so; your code using `word` directly is equivalent.

But using `word` directly is mildly confusing to people reading the code; after the first pointer increment, `word` no longer points to the actual word, so if you later needed to refer to the word as a whole, you can't, but a maintainer might *think* you could because you still have `word` available. Making the copy into `p` avoids that semantic disagreement between the variable name and what it represents. An optimizing compiler would likely produce the same machine code anyway (`word` is never used again, so `word` and `p` could be implemented as the *same* variable), and even if it didn't, as long as you're not running out of registers it hardly matters if it actually uses two different pointers.